# Hide Element with same data-attr but not the one clicked

Tags: javascript, click, custom-data-attribute

I have 2 seperated elements with buttons to control the same thing.
[image]

I've set up a `data-attr` so 2 elements (which do the same thing) have the same `data-attr` value - for example `dosomething` on the top left has the same data-attr value as `domething2` on the bottom left.

Now I want to hide `dosomething2` on the bottom left when `dosomething` on the top left is clicked - and when `dosomething` on the top left is clicked it should hide itself.

So for "*and when `dosomething` on the top left is clicked it should hide itself.*"
I made this:

```
$('.dosomething').click(function (evt) {
        $('.dosomething').fadeIn()
        $(this).fadeOut()
})
```

I can't figure out how to make my:

```
$('.dosomething2').click(function (evt) {
```

get the `dosomething` on the top with their same `data-attr` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this can help you. But you can use data-attr like below.

jQuery

```
$('a[data-dosomething="true"]').click(function(event) {
  $(this).fadeOut()
});
```

HTML

```
<a data-dosomething="true" href="#"> dosomething</a>
<a data-dosomething="true" href="#"> dosomething 2</a>
```

Comment: with that example I would need to declare every data-attr with its value seperated and make a click function for each

Comment: No need for a click function for each. This function will trigger click event for all elements which have data attribute 'data-dosomething'

Comment: I took your solution and wrote it a little different for my projects and now it works perfectly fine. Thanks for your approach